# Disable csrf using Java configuration

Tags: java, spring

Good Day,

I am trying to learn Spring.
I am currently doing this guide: http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

I have followed all instructions, however, when I try to run the application,
403 Forbidden is displayed.

I searched the net and found out that it is due to the csrf protection.
And so, I proceeded to search the net how to disable csrf.
Here is my Java configuration:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I use this configuration?
Specifically, at which part of the code should I insert it?

Here are the other 2 classes as stated in the tutorial. All of them belong to the same package (Hello).

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Page {
    private String name;
    private String about;
    private String phone;
    private String website;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getAbout() {
        return about;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }
}

public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Page page = restTemplate.getForObject("http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware", Page.class);
        System.out.println("Name:       " + page.getName());
        System.out.println("About:      " + page.getAbout());
        System.out.println("Phone:      " + page.getPhone());
        System.out.println("Website:    " + page.getWebsite());
    }

}
```

Comment: Good day :) The guide linked is for a project "consuming REST" (i.e. client side). CSRF protection is something that is set up on the server side, not the client side (or it would be a silly protection ;p).

Comment: I see. So how do you explain why I keep getting the 403 Forbidden error message?

Comment: No 403 from here: https://gist.github.com/Regisc/65c1290cdc8feadad3c7

Comment: Where did you get that result? I tried http://graph.facebook.com/pivotalsoftware in the browser and it is successful. However, when I tried it in Spring using the tutorial, I get a 403 Forbidden error.

Comment: I used some command line tool, maybe you should post your current code

Comment: Hello sir, I've updated the details to include the other Java classes as stated in the tutorial.

Comment: I git cloned [the sample project](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-consuming-rest.git), `cd` into `gs-consuming-rest/complete`, `mvn clean package && java -jar target/gs-consuming-rest-0.1.0.jar` and no issue here.

Comment: I used the initial project. I will try the complete project and see what happens. Thanks for the inputs.

Comment: @roberto I had the same problem, at the end, I made the "Application" the class that extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and it worked. I am not really happy with it but might help you too.

Answer (score 1):

Add `@Configuration` on the `WebSecurityConfig` class and it will be automatically scanned when you will launch your Spring Application. You don't need to write any code.

Here is the code with `@Configuration`

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sadly, putting @Configuration did not work. I tried to run the Application.java and Error 403 Forbidden is displayed. WebSecurityConfig.java is in the same package with both Application.java and Page.java

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your url is valid.

In my case the url was generated by code and was in different case so I got 403 forbidden error. Spend lot of time trying to fix the issue by enabling security config.