# Spring Security - Posting to an unsecured page results in a 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following form on an unsecured page, start.html:

```
<form action="approve" method="POST">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I'm using Spring Boot starter security to configure security as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**", "/js/**", "/lib/**", "/fonts/**", "/start.html", "/approve")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll();
    }
```

When the form is submitted, it is handled by a controller:

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApprovalController {

    @RequestMapping("/approve")
     public @ResponseBody void handleRequest(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
         //write to the output stream of response, etc.
     }
}
```

But when a post request is made to approve, I get the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

// current date
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.
```

How do I specify that posts to the approve controller should be unsecured?

Answer (score 2):

You are getting 403 because you are not sending the [CSRF token](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html).

You should add the CSRF token as hidden input of the form:

```
  <input type='hidden' value='${_csrf.token}' name='${_csrf.parameterName}'/>
```

or [disable CSRF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29875589/disable-csrf-using-java-configuration)